# Predict one variable based on another similar

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models

I have two times series: A and B, they are highly correlated.
I would like to build the model A~B,however, I have observed that A moves up **earlier** than B and much faster. Later, after the shock, A decreases also much faster.
Do you have any hints how can I build the model?

Files:

a) A: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am9f1Ox4hcd-6VizdMp9r3sbWIYe?e=HiTGBF

b) B: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am9f1Ox4hcd-6VkG6TvCkY0Id6DC?e=Fc2OfB

[image: A vs B Hist data]

Comment: If you are happy with my response ..then accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your 78 quarterly values and arbitrarily selected A as the output series and B as the input. I used AUTOBOX a piece of software that I have helped to develop in it's optionally totally automatic mode. It follows the Transfer Function paradigm http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/A.pdf to form a SARMAX model https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf .

While both series themselves are non-stationary themselves , the equation/relationship between them required no differencing operators. This phenomenon is not unusual at all .

Model diagnostics from a tentative TF model suggested the need for a (visually obvious) level shift indicator at period 38 (2009/2) and  two pulse indicators (periods 71 and 9 ... 2017/3 & 2002/1  ) and an AR(1) component.

The model used both a contemporary direct effect of B and an indirect effect of B lagged twice in order to predict Y.

The method used to identify these three latent determinstic structures is here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html .

The Actual/Fit and Forecast graph is here [image] with equation here [image] and here [image]

The statistics for the model are here [image]

The model residual plot suggests both mean and error variance constancy . [image] with an ACF here [image] . AUTOBOX at one point tentatively considered a second level shift at period 38 (2009/2) but found it not-significant.

The forecasts for the next 12 quarters reflect the uncertainty in the predictions for the input series B and the possibility of future pulses . [image] . The limits were generated using montecarlo procedures providing a complete probability distribution for each forecast period.

The Actuals & Cleansed graph highlight the level shift (intercept change) and the two (now !) clear pulses.

The "shock" that you allude to is a "permanent effect" .

In conclusion to form this model the following 5 characterics needed to be identified

1 What level of differencing needs to be included (if any )
2 what is the form of the relationship
3 Is there a level shift needed to deal with an exogenous unstated factor
4 are there one-time only effects needed to deal with exogenous factors
5 What is the impact of omitted stochastic series i.e.the form of the ARMA structure.
6 What power transformation or weighted least squares approach is needed to deal with non-constant error variance through time

Comment: IrishStat When they give you the data, you know how to treat them!

Comment: tu ...for your nice words.

Comment: Thank you IrishStat for your work - this is very useful.
Could you please help me to understand one of your comment:
'While both series themselves are non-stationary themselves , the equation/relationship between them required no differencing operators. This phenomenon is not unusual at all .' I thought stationarity of the variables is a must?

Comment: A stationary time series is one whose statistical properties such as mean, variance, autocorrelation, etc. are all constant over time . With causal models the "relationship" between the variables must be the same i.e. constant or stationary or consistent over time .

Comment: iff the model is sufficient then the errors from the model will be information-less being whit noise ..thus predictable. Reversing the equation then leads to predictions which ought to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a result in R, using the `auto.arima` function in the `forecast` package. auto.arima automatically determines the necessary AR, MA, d, S components and also allows you to include other variables.

```
> library(readxl)
> A=read_excel("A.xlsx")
> B=read_excel("B.xlsx")

> A1=ts(A$Value,frequency=4)
> B1=ts(B$Value,frequency=4)

> library(forecast)
> mod=auto.arima(A1,xreg=B1,stepwise=F,approximation=F)
> summary(mod)

Series: A1 
Regression with ARIMA(0,1,0) errors 

Coefficients:
        xreg
      0.4091
s.e.  0.1570

sigma^2 estimated as 0.002247:  log likelihood=126.03
AIC=-248.06   AICc=-247.89   BIC=-243.37

Training set error measures:
                       ME       RMSE        MAE        MPE     MAPE
Training set -0.001337502 0.04678851 0.03242543 -0.3753579 5.792672
                  MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.4114466 0.08525872
```

So the selected model contains only 1 term, the lag of B. Check the residuals:

```
> checkresiduals(mod)

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from Regression with ARIMA(0,1,0) errors
Q* = 7.354, df = 7, p-value = 0.393

Model df: 1.   Total lags used: 8
```

Look OK. Let's try a model without B:

```
> mod=auto.arima(A1,stepwise=F,approximation=F)
> summary(mod)

Series: A1 
ARIMA(1,1,0) 

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.1743
s.e.  0.1114

sigma^2 estimated as 0.002369:  log likelihood=123.98
AIC=-243.95   AICc=-243.79   BIC=-239.26

Training set error measures:
                       ME       RMSE        MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.001066886 0.04804238 0.03242514 -0.55368 5.841148 0.4114429
                    ACF1
Training set -0.01470753

> checkresiduals(mod)

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(1,1,0)
Q* = 4.033, df = 7, p-value = 0.776

Model df: 1.   Total lags used: 8
```

This model is very similar to the previous in terms of accuracy, and includes only 1 AR term, suggesting that you may as well forecast based on A alone.